# Got javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException when deploy it in server

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I have RMI desktop application. My problem with xsl template for generating report. Here i included the XSL and java method for your reference

It works fine when tested in my local machine and happens only when i connect it into server remote machine.

I tried answer which already posted in this site, but it cannot resolve my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"  
    xmlns:nds="http://com.test"
    xmlns:dconv="xalan://com.test.server.BaseConverter"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    xmlns:model="xalan://com.test.server.AbstractModel"
    extension-element-prefixes="dconv java model"
    exclude-result-prefixes="nds dconv java model" >

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <nds:Result     ResultDir="ModDir" ResultName="Report_Import"/>
    <nds:PreReq Name=".import0.xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="converter" select="'instanceof com.test.server.BaseConverter'"/>
    <xsl:param name="sourceModel" select="'instanceof com.test.server.AbstractModel'"/>               
    <xsl:param name="resultModel" select="'instanceof com.test.server.AbstractModel'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="title" select="'DMS-100 Data Import Report'" />
    <xsl:variable name="log" select="'.import0.xml'" />

    <xsl:template match="/OfficeData">
    <HTML>
        <xsl:call-template name="header">
            <xsl:with-param name="title" select="$title"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    <BODY>
        <xsl:call-template name="office-meta">
            <xsl:with-param name="title" select="$title"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(model:getURL($sourceModel, $log))"/>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my java code

```
AbstractModel.java

public String getURL(String filename) {
    // some code
    return urlstr;
}
```

Exception

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: The first argument to the non-static Java function 'getURL' is not a valid object reference.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1017)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:789)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformerHandler(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1093)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance and please let me know if any info you need.

Comment: Does the server use the same XSLT engine as your machine does?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen : Yes same XSLT engine

Comment: sounds like sourceModel is not properly set then.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen : How to debug it. But it is working fine in my local machine

Comment: print statements?  An IDE with an XSLT debugger? You are the only one knowing the information needed to answer your own question.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen : Is there any relation on Java version. My system java version 1.8 whereas server has 1.7. Does it affect anything?